# Visual Studio 2015 won't start debugging with ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2015

I am working with on an ASP.NET app with multiple startup projects in my solution. For some odd reason, when I start debugging, my browser will open and VS will change from blue to orange (indicating that debugging has started), then a second later it stops debugging. I don't see any errors.

If I spam the debugger, it will start debugging. I've tried on 3 different computers, all same issue.

Comment: You may have an infinite loop. I ran into a similar problem the other day.  In my case I was _newing-up_ an instance of a class inside a member variable of the same class type... I know, I know... But anyway, this could be one reason... for what it is worth, I hope it helps.